Property of an "isotropic" function
We say that a function $F: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is isotropic if, given any vector $b\in \mathbb{R}^n$, the function $u\mapsto F(u) \cdot b$ is either convex, concave, or linear.
How can I prove that $F$ is isotropic if and only if there is a unit vector $a$ and a convex scalar-valued function $f$ such that $F(u) = a f(u)$?

Context from this article

Following Crandall and Majda we say that the flux $F: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is isotropic if, given any vector $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$, the function $u\to F(u)\cdot b$ is either convex, concave, or linear. These authors observe that (1.1) is a model for the equations of inviscid gas dynamics only when $F$ is isotropic.
On the other hand, one easily proves that $F$ is isotropic if and only if there is a unit vector $a$ and a convex scalar-valued function $f$ such that $F(u)=f(u)a.$ In this case (1.1) becomes the one-dimensional equation
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac\partial{\partial a}f(u)=0. \tag{1.5}$$
Thus the restriction that $F$ be isotropic is a fairly severe one.


What have you tried?

I know how to prove the converse implication (if $F(u) = a f(u)$ then $F$ is isotropic). I have some difficulties with the other implication.

Let $n=2$ and $F(u) = (1, u)$. Then $F(u) \cdot b = b_1 + b_2 u$ is linear but $F(u)$ is not of the form $a f(u)$ for some unit vector $a$ and univariate function $f$. Are you sure the question is posed correctly?

The function $u\mapsto b_1 + u b_2$ is not linear (with respect to the variable $u$). If you define $g(u) = b_1 + u b_2$ then $g(u+v) \ne g(u) + g(v)$, except for the trivial case $b_1 = 0$.

Let $F(u) = (u, u^2)$. Then $F(u) \cdot b = b_1 u + b_2 u^2$. This is concave or convex when $b_2 \ne 0$, and linear when $b_2 = 0$. But it is not of the form $af(u)$.

I answered with the definition in the article, maybe it refers to something different

Notation:

$F(u)$ can be written as $(f_1(u), \ldots, f_n(u))$ for univariate functions $f_i$.
Let $g_b(u) := F(u) \cdot b$.

If the $f_i$ are twice differentiable, then $$g''_b(u) = (f''_1(u), \ldots, f''_n(u)) \cdot b.$$ For each choice of $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we want this quantity to have the same sign over all $u$, so that $g_b$ is concave/convex/linear.

Lemma. Suppose for each $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the elements of the set $\{g''_b(u) : u \in \mathbb{R}\}$ have the same sign (although the sign may differ for different choices of $b$). Then the span of the set $\{(f''_1(u), \ldots, f''_n(u)) : u \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is one-dimensional.


Proof: We prove the contrapositive. Suppose there exist $u_1$ and $u_2$ such that $v_1 := (f''_1(u_1), \ldots, f''_n(u_1))$ and $v_2 := (f''_1(u_2), \ldots, f''_n(u_2))$ are linearly independent. Then $b := v_1/\|v_1\| - v_2/\|v_2\| \ne 0$ is such that $$v_1 \cdot b = \frac{\|v_1\|\|v_2\| - v_1 \cdot v_2}{\|v_1 \| \|v_2\|} = - \frac{\|v_1\|\|v_2\| - v_1 \cdot v_2}{\|v_1 \| \|v_2\|}  = - v_2 \cdot b,$$ and moreover $v_1 \cdot b \ne 0$ due to the equality criterion for the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality not holding when $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent. Thus for this choice of $b$, the values $g''_b(u_1)$ and $g''_b(u_2)$ have different signs.

The lemma implies the vectors $(f''_1(u), \ldots, f''_n(u))$ for all $u$ lie in a one-dimensional subspace. Assuming $f''_1(u) \ne 0$ for all $u$, we have $a=(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ with $a_i=f''_i(u)/f''_1(u)$ such that
$$(f''_1(u), \ldots, f''_n(u)) = a f''_1(u) ,\qquad \forall u \in \mathbb{R}.$$
This implies $$f_i(u) = a_i f_1(u) + b_i u + c_i, \qquad \forall i.\tag{$*$}$$ If $b_i=c_i=0$ for all $i$, this becomes $F(u) = af_1(u)$. By taking $b=(1,0,\ldots, 0)$, we know $f''_1(u)$ is either always positive or always negative, so either $\|a\|f_1(u)$ or $-\|a\|f_1(u)$ is be convex. Thus $F(u) = (\pm a/\|a\|) (\mp \|a\| f_1(u))$ puts $F(u)$ in the desired form in Hoff's definition of isotropic given in your question.
However I do not see how to impose the restriction that $b_i=c_i=0$ for all $i$. Indeed in the Crandall and Majda paper cited by Hoff, equation (0.6) looks more like my ($*$) above since it has the lower order terms.

So perhaps Hoff is imposing some initial conditions like $f_i(0)=0$ and $f'_i(0)=0$ or something.
